# Spring Retry: How to make all methods of a @Bean retryable?

Tags: spring, spring-retry

I would like to create a `@Bean` of a third party service like Keycloak (or any other) which may or may not be reachable at any given time. This object should retry all methods of the resulting `Keycloak` bean.

I have tried the following:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
class KeycloakBeanProvider() {

    @Bean
    @Retryable
    fun keycloak(oauth2ClientRegistration: ClientRegistration): Keycloak {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
            .realm(oauth2ClientRegistration.clientName)
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .clientId(oauth2ClientRegistration.clientId)
            .clientSecret(oauth2ClientRegistration.clientSecret)
            .build()
    }
}
```

But this way only the bean creation will be retried, not actual method calls on the bean. I know `@Retryable` can be used on class level but I don't own the `Keycloak` class so I can't add it there.

How can I make the methods of the resulting `Keycloak` bean retryable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate the `Keycloak` with `@Retryable`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So70593939Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So70593939Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            foo.foo("called foo");
            foo.bar("called bar");
        };
    }

}

@Component
@Retryable
class Foo {

    public void foo(String in) {
        System.out.println("foo");
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    public void bar(String in) {
        System.out.println("bar");
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception ex, String in) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + ":" + in);
    }

}
```

```
foo
foo
foo
test:called foo
bar
bar
bar
test:called bar
```

If you can't annotate the class (e.g. because it's from another project), you need to use a `RetryTemplate` to call its methods instead of using annotation-based retry.

Comment: I feared that. I'll probably just wrap the methods I need in a Service and make that class retryable then.

Comment: A simple solution would be to create a retryable delegating class with each method delegating to the actual `Keycloak` method. Then use the delegating class everywhere.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I meant. Also I stumbled onto the problem, that the `Keycloak` object itself for some operations creates more service objects which again need to be retryable. Something like `keycloak.users().delete(id)`. So I will probably go with an extended delegate-approach, in which I can have a method `deleteUser(id)` that is retryable. Since I only need a small part of the methods `Keycloak`offers, I think it's okay to have a single class delegating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually instrument your class. Check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html#declarativeRetry).

```
@Bean
public Keycloak myService() {
    ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(RepeatOperations.class.getClassLoader());
    factory.setInterfaces(Keycloak.class);
    factory.setTarget(createKeycloak());

    Keycloak keycloak = (Keycloak) factory.getProxy();
    JdkRegexpMethodPointcut pointcut = new JdkRegexpMethodPointcut();
    pointcut.setPatterns(".*.*");

    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor = new RetryOperationsInterceptor();

    ((Advised) keycloak).addAdvisor(new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, interceptor));

    return keycloak;
}
```